# How to check field conditions in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code of MySQL:

```
$sqlstd = mysql_query(
   "SELECT   cd.cf_did AS id,
             cd.cf_companyname AS name,
             cd.cf_description AS descp,
             cd.cf_payment AS pay,
             cd.cf_status AS status,
             GROUP_CONCAT(ct.cf_ctname SEPARATOR ', ') AS cranetype
    FROM     cf_directory cd,
             cf_cranetype ct
    WHERE    FIND_IN_SET(ct.cf_ctid, cd.cf_cranetype)
    GROUP BY cd.cf_did,
             cd.cf_companyname,
             cd.cf_description,
             cd.cf_payment,
             cd.cf_status
    ORDER BY cd.cf_did DESC LIMIT 4",
    $con);
```

I want to check 2 `WHERE` conditions in this query: `cd.cf_payment='top' AND cd.cf_status='1'`.

I am using this code:

```
$sqlstd = mysql_query(
   "SELECT   cd.cf_did AS id,
             cd.cf_companyname AS name,
             cd.cf_description AS descp,
             cd.cf_payment AS pay,
             cd.cf_status AS status,
             GROUP_CONCAT(ct.cf_ctname SEPARATOR ', ') AS cranetype
    FROM     cf_directory cd,
             cf_cranetype ct
    WHERE    cd.cf_payment='top',
             cd.cf_status='1'
         AND FIND_IN_SET(ct.cf_ctid, cd.cf_cranetype)
    GROUP By cd.cf_did,
             cd.cf_companyname,
             cd.cf_description,
             cd.cf_payment,
             cd.cf_status
    ORDER BY cd.cf_did DESC
    LIMIT 4",
    $con);
```

but it's not working.

How can I add 2 field (`cf_payment`, `cf_status`) checks in `WHERE` condition?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the old and deprecated mysql_* functions. Please go to php.net and look up PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHERE conditions are concatenated with `AND`/ `OR` not with comma.

Update

```
WHERE cd.cf_payment='top',cd.cf_status='1'
```

To:

```
WHERE cd.cf_payment='top' AND cd.cf_status='1'
```

**Note:** Please avoid using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Use `PDO_*` or `mysqli_*`.